# What is the URI of Bing Vision?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-runtime, mediaelement

I know the method of going into Lens Picker and manually launching Bing Vision, but the app [Tile for Bing Vision](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/tile-for-bing-vision/05894022-e18c-40a4-a6cc-992383aa7ee8) can open Bing Vision without going into Lens Picker. How can that behavior be replicated?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API exposed by the platform for launching Bing Vision directly, and there is no published URI that I am aware of.

The list of URIs supported by the platform out-of-the-box are listed [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662937(v=vs.105).aspx)

It is possible that Bing Vision supports an internal scheme for launching itself.

Comment: What's the other way of doing that?